# Hook into Orientation Change not override it completely

Tags: android

I am currently trying to "hook into" the orientation change event of `Android` so that I can perform some actions during this event, im currently using the `onConfigurationChanged` and    `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` combo as per the docs but the problem with this is that it seems to require you to handle all orientation actions manually or they wont happen at all once your "hooked into" it.

All i want to do is have the normal orientation change events occur but with my additional ones tacked on, is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the stuff handles automatically, like resizing layout, repositioning ActionBar etc, so you don't need to "rotate" anything manually.
What you need to handle manually is:

- having different images / texts for portrait and landscape mode
- having different layouts for portrait and landscape mode
- having different configurations (like number of GridView columns)
- etc

If you don't have the stuff above specified for different orientations, there is nothing for you to handle.

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    //do your stuff here
}
```

However if there are different resources you have to apply them manually. Try it out as it is and then you will see what handled automatically, and what is needed to be re-assigned by you.

Comment: I do indeed have a different layout between the two orientations, I hoping not to handle anything like that manually as it works (mostly) fine when I don't catch the change, but I guess I'll have to, thanks